# add calculated column into Qt QSqlQueryModel

Tags: c++, qt

I am going to calculate new row for each result from this subjacent

```cpp
QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel();
model->setQuery("SELECT height,age from patients", DB->getDB());
model->setHeaderData(4,Qt::Horizontal,tr("height"));
model->setHeaderData(2,Qt::Horizontal,tr("age"));
ui->tableView->setModel(model);    
ui->tableView->show();
```

as

```
ratio = height/age;
```

can I do it? how?

thank You!

Comment: You could just calculate the ratio in the query itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it.

you can access the items in the `QSqlQueryModel` like:

```
QSqlRecord rec = model->record(row); // get the row you need
QVariant height = rec.field("height").value(); // or access it via index
QVariant age = rec.field("age").value();
double ratio = height.toDouble() / age.toDouble();
```

just adapt the code to your need and maybe add value checks to it.

cheers

Comment: ok, but how to add this calculated value as new column in QSQLQueryModel, to display all rows/columns in QTableView

Comment: in that case i would use `QStandardItemModel`. use a `QSqlQuery` to receive the data, calculate the `ratio` and add them to the model for display (might be possible with `QSqlQueryModel` but i've never done such task)

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for help... i did it so:

```
        QSqlQuery pyt(DB->getDB());
        pyt.prepare("SELECT h,a from patients");
        pyt.exec();

        QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(0,3,this);
        model->setHeaderData(0,Qt::Horizontal,tr("heigh"));
        model->setHeaderData(1,Qt::Horizontal,tr("age"));
        model->setHeaderData(2,Qt::Horizontal,tr("ratio"));

        while (pyt.next())
        {
           QList<QStandardItem*> NewRow;
           QString age = pyt.value(0).toString();
           QStandardItem *newColumn = new QStandardItem(age);
           NewRow.append(newColumn);
           QString height = pyt.value(1).toString();
           newColumn = new QStandardItem(height);
           NewRow.append(newColumn);
           newColumn = new QStandardItem(QVariant("MY RATIO"));
           NewRow.append(newColumn);

           model->appendRow(NewRow); 
        }

        ui->tableView->setModel(model);
        ui->tableView->show();
```